# Deep copy of linked list c++

Tags: visual-c++, linked-list, deep-copy

I'm trying to make a deep copy for my simple linked list that I've made. I'm trying to get the basics of it and any help would be appreciated. I just want to take the first value in the old list and deep copy it to the new list.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct listrec
{
char        value;
struct listrec    *next;
};


void deepcopy(listrec *old_linked_list,  listrec *new_linked_list)
{

while(old_linked_list != NULL)
{
    new_linked_list->value = old_linked_list->value;
    new_linked_list->next = old_linked_list->next;
    old_linked_list = old_linked_list->next;
    new_linked_list = new_linked_list->next;
}
}



int main()
{
listrec x1,x2,x3;
listrec *head_old, *head_new=NULL;

x1.value = 'a';
x1.next = &x2;

x2.value = 'c';
x2.next = &x3;

x3.value = 'w';
x3.next = NULL;

head_old = &x1;
head_new = head_old;

deepcopy(head_old, head_new);

//print old list
cout<<"Old List: "<<endl;
while(head_old != NULL)
{
    cout<<head_old->value<<endl;
    head_old= head_old->next;
}

cout<<endl;

//print copied list
cout<<"Copied list: "<<endl;
while(head_new != NULL)
{
    cout<<head_new->value<<endl;
    head_new= head_new->next;
}


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

The program works and it makes a copy but I just want to make sure its a deep copy and not a shallow copy. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `head_new` which is NULL to `deepcopy`. Then you try to deference (access) it. This gives you segmentation fault (error), since you cannot deference a NULL pointer. (You cannot access nothing, because your pointer points to nothing.)

To correct your code must allocate memory for `head_new` in `main` and for each next node in in `deepcopy`. Also you should move on your `new_linked_list`, as you assign all the time to the same node.

Comment: Could you please explain further? I know this may sound stupid but I just don't understand.

Comment: @ClaudiuBadau Improved my answer.

Comment: how would I allocate memory for head_new in my main? Should I just delete head_new=NULL and replace it with listrec *head_new = new listrec?

Comment: @ClaudiuBadau Oh sorry.. this is not intended to be a lesson on memory allocation.

Comment: I'm sorry. I understand. I set head_new = head_old and in my deepcopy just moved on my new_linked_list like you've suggested and it copied my list but I just want to make sure this is a deep copy and not a shallow copy.